# Passing char * array to another function, Pointer trouble in c

Tags: c, pointers

Hey i am having trouble getting the proper value stored into the CHANNELS char array. I really think it could be a simple problem with my pointers. I "think" i understand that when you declare char *CHANNELS[6] you are creating an array of pointers. so i pass through in my switch statement case 1 CHANNELS in the third argument i am not getting the proper value back. Any help is great! Some back ground: I am reading in 6 "channels" that each have 6 binary values.

```
void binEnter(void *channel, char *CHANNELS[6], int i){
redo:
    printf("Enter binary value for Channel %d: ",i);
    scanf("%s",(UCHAR *)channel);
    if (strlen(channel)!=6) {
        printf("Error entry must be six digits!\n");
        goto redo;
    }
    char *string = channel;
    int j;
    for (j = 0; j < 6; j++){
        if ((string[j] != '0') && (string[j] != '1')){
            printf("Error did not enter a binary number!\n");
            goto redo;
        }
    }
CHANNELS[i]=channel;
printf("Channel %d is stored as %s\n",i,CHANNELS[i]);
```

}

```
int main(){
int selection;
UCHAR channel0;
UCHAR channel1;
UCHAR channel2;
UCHAR channel3;
UCHAR channel4;
UCHAR channel5;
char *CHANNELS[6];
float vRefVal[6];
//char *data[5];
float volt =0;
do {
start:
    promptUser();
    scanf("%d",&selection);
    switch (selection) {
        case 1:
            binEnter(&channel0, CHANNELS,0);
            binEnter(&channel1, CHANNELS,1);
            binEnter(&channel2, CHANNELS,2);
            binEnter(&channel3, CHANNELS,3);
            binEnter(&channel4, CHANNELS,4);
            binEnter(&channel5, CHANNELS,5);
            int i;
            for (i=0; i<6; i++) {
                printf("Channel %d is %s in main\n", i, CHANNELS[i]);
            }
            goto start;

        case 2:
            goto start;
        case 3:
            enterVolt(&volt);
            printf("Volt = %f\n",volt);
            goto start;
        case 4:
            if (volt) {
                vRefCal(&volt, CHANNELS, vRefVal);
                printVref(vRefVal);
                goto start;
            }
            else{
                printf("Must enter input Vref first!\n");
                goto start;
            }
        default:
            break;
    }
} while (selection!=5);
return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`UCHAR channel0;`

you have passed as

`binEnter(&channel0, CHANNELS,0);`

The prototype of `bitEnter` is `void binEnter(void *channel, char *CHANNELS[6], int i)`

But then you do: `scanf("%s",(UCHAR *)channel);`

1. Why do you pass it as `void *` if you are going to process it as a string?
2. You are trying to input a string, where the type is of `UCHAR` (which i assume to be an unsigned character). Doing this will overwrite the memory starting from the base of the address stored in `channel`, and depending on how the memory was allocated to the automatic variables they will be overwritten, an undefined behaviour.

Try dynamically allocating the strings which you input in the `bitEnter` function and then add it to the `CHANNELS` ?